# Remove rewrite endpoint on deactivation?

Tags: rewrite-rules

I'm using Milo's [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/154813/11202) to add a Rewrite Endpoint as part of my plugin.

Is there a straight-forward way to remove a Rewrite Rule upon deactivation?

I found [this snippet](http://wordpress-hackers.1065353.n5.nabble.com/How-do-I-remove-rewrite-rules-td39876.html#a39894) but I'd expect a "remove_rewrite_endpoint" to match [add_rewrite_endpoint](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint)

Also, how do I know what to look for in the rewrite rules list when add_rewrite_endpoint was used to add the rule?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is flush the rewrite rules on deactivation. For example, in the main plugin file:

```
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, function() {
    flush_rewrite_rules();
});
```

Comment: How does it know which rewrite rule(s) to remove?

Comment: Flushing removes all rewrite rules with no distinction. Then they are rebuilt again from scratch.

Comment: Are they rebuilt on the fly bit by bit as needed, or are they rebuilt all at once as soon as needed?

Comment: I'm not fully sure but as far I understand, they are all rebuilt at once in next page load and stored in database until they are flushed again. This database operation is the reason why flushing rewrite rules must be used carefully, only one time if is needed, never on every page load. For example, in this answer is used only on plugin activation because the plugin affect rewrite rules and need to be flushed.

Comment: The original question asks about how to remove a rewrite endpoint which was previously added with using `add_rewrite_endpoint`. Following your logic, it is still unclear how flushing rewrite rules will remove the registered endpoint. If flushing removes endpoints, then deactivating the 2nd plugin that flushes rewrite rules would also remove rewrite rules added by the 1st plugin. When calling `flush_rewrite_rules()`, you do not specify which rules you want to remove. That is why I asked - how does it know which rewrite rule(s) to remove and which not to?

Comment: I answered your question previously. **`flush_rewrite_rules()` removes all rewrite rules with no distinction**. Then, in the next page load, WordPress rebuilds all rewrite rules found in the core or in plugins. If you have a plugin that register a rewrite endpoint and you deactivate the plugin without flushing the rewrite rules, the endpoint will be still in the database even if you delete de plugin, until rewrite rules are flushed and rebuilt (by a plugin or manually); that is why plugins that add or modify rewrite rules must use `flush_rewrite_rules()` on activation and also on deactivation.

Comment: Does it mean that `add_rewrite_endpoint ` must be called on every page load?

Comment: Yes, on `init` action hook preferably. You may be interested in a question I made some time ago where I learn that: [Rewrite rules go away](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/112633/rewrite-rules-goes-away).

Comment: Except, on `init` the plugin is registering this endpoint, and the deactivation function runs after that... so you're just registering that endpoint one last time and flushing rewrite rules before the plugin deactivates. Try it. You can comment out the flush_rewrite_rules call upon activation, but that endpoint is still there. We need a way to remove the endpoint AFTER deactivation, but the "plugin_deactivated" function doesn't fire once your plugin has been deactivated - because it's not active. You need ANOTHER plugin that runs flush_rewrite_rules() on ANY plugin deactivation... feels bad.